# Trivial cohomology with free module coefficient

Tags: homotopy-theory, cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a group and $M$ be a free $\mathbb{Z} G$-module. Then $H^2(G,M)=0$. Is this statement correct?

I know that if $M$ is injective module, then $H^n(G,M)=0$ for all $n\geq 1$. But I have no idea how to show that a free $\mathbb{Z} G$-module is a injective module.

Beside, since $M$ is a free module, it is a projective module. Hence the it $H_n(G,M)=0$ for all $n\geq 1$. Is this fact helpful for me to proof $H^2(G,M)=0$?

Answer (score 6):

Assume G acts by translation. If G is finite yes, $H^n(G,\mathbb{Z}G)=0$ for all $n>0$. In general no: If G is finitely presented then $H^2(G,\mathbb{Z}G)$ is either 0 or $\mathbb{Z}$ or infinitely generated (and torsion-free). If $|G:H|<\infty$ then $H^n(G,\mathbb{Z}G)=H^n(H,\mathbb{Z}H)$.
These are standard facts, try looking in Ken Brown's bible, and definitely in his good friend Geoghegan's book *"Topological Methods in Group Theory"* (section 13.2), and Brown-Geoghegan's paper *"Cohomology with free coefficients of the fundamental group of a graph of groups".*

Actually, I realize that I gave this answer to a similar question asked here: [What if the low-degree cohomology of a $G$-module and all its restrictions vanish?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/200078/what-if-the-low-degree-cohomology-of-a-g-module-and-all-its-restrictions-vanis?rq=1)
I pointed to Brown's chapter *"Cohomologically Trivial Modules"* for a proof. The original source is Rim's paper *"Modules over finite groups"*.